# using sed in a loop on a single file

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I require to make 58 changes to be done on a html file.
The for loop runs 29 times

It contains the below sed command. Every run of the for loop replaces 2 place holders out of 58

```
sed "s?$Plc_hldr1?$DateTime?;s?$Plc_hldr2?$Total?" html_format.htm >> html_final.htm
```

I am using above command which makes changes in the original file on every loop and appends it into the html_final.htm file.

Thus there are 29 copies of html_format.htm in html_final.htm.

I require only 1 copy of the html_format.htm with all the 58 place holder values replaced.

Below is the small example of the whole table:

```
01/02/2014      15
%%DDMS2RT%%     %%DDMS2C%%
%%DDMS3RT%%     %%DDMS3C%%
%%DDMS4RT%%     %%DDMS4C%%
%%DDMS5RT%%     %%DDMS5C%%
%%DDMS6RT%%     %%DDMS6C%%
%%DDMS7RT%%     %%DDMS7C%%
```

after the 2nd for loop below is the content of the html_final.htm

```
01/02/2014      15
%%DDMS2RT%%     %%DDMS2C%%
%%DDMS3RT%%     %%DDMS3C%%
%%DDMS4RT%%     %%DDMS4C%%
%%DDMS5RT%%     %%DDMS5C%%
%%DDMS6RT%%     %%DDMS6C%%
%%DDMS7RT%%     %%DDMS7C%%

%%DDMS1RT%%     %%DDMS1C%%
01/02/2014      817
%%DDMS3RT%%     %%DDMS3C%%
%%DDMS4RT%%     %%DDMS4C%%
%%DDMS5RT%%     %%DDMS5C%%
%%DDMS6RT%%     %%DDMS6C%%
%%DDMS7RT%%     %%DDMS7C%%
```

Note that the same table is appended once again after the 2nd for loop and the place holder in the 2nd row contains the values, value in 1st row is again replaced by the placeholders.

What I would like is the below output. i.e. 1 single table instead of multiple copies and all the place holders replaced within that table itself

```
01/02/2014      15
01/02/2014      817
01/02/2014      512
01/02/2014      765
%%DDMS5RT%%     %%DDMS5C%%
%%DDMS6RT%%     %%DDMS6C%%
%%DDMS7RT%%     %%DDMS7C%%
```

I tried to play with sed -i but it is not available in AIX unix.

I really hope I have explained expressed it very clearly and my question is not an XY problem anymore!!

Comment: What does the final file look like? A header and 29 copies of the template? Is there any reason not to have the 29 copies in a single template in the first place? The whole question smacks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this!! I am changing the details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would surely be to use `>` rather than `>>`.

`>>` is used to concatenate the output of standard out to the specified file.

`>` is used to write the output from standard out to the specified file, replacing the old file if it already exists.

i.e.

```
sed "s?$Plc_hldr1?$DateTime?;s?$Plc_hldr2?$Total?" html_format.htm > html_final.htm
cp html_final.htm html_format.htm
```

Comment: agreed, but that would be useful if I did not use the for loop. using > say in the 2nd run of for would replace any changes done in the 1st run of the loop.

Comment: I need all the 58 place holders replaced in one copy

Comment: @user3055262 I don't see how the 2nd iteration could overwrite the changes in the 1st. The placeholder in the 1st will be gone, as it was replaced. If you still disagree, then please add a sample of your loop in the question.

Comment: @janos I have added all the details.

Answer (score 0):

If we imagine that your real problem statement is "how do I piece together a HTML table from fragments I retrieve e.g. from a database", the answer might look something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Output HTML header

cat <<'____HERE'
<html><head><title>Table</title></head>
  <body><table>
    <tr><th>Date</th><th>Result</th></tr>
____HERE

# Obtain results from database
sql 'select date, result from table;'  |

# Read each record, format an HTML table fragment
while read date result; do
    cat <<________HERE
        <tr><td>$date</td><td>$result</td></tr>
________HERE
done

# Output HTML footer
cat <<____HERE
</table></body></html>
____HERE
```

The script prints an HTML page on its standard output. Redirect to a file if you want it in a file.

(Sorry if my HTML skills are rusty. It's been a while...)